# VBA Document Classification when saving file

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script to auto save a file that is modified through vba.

I am receiving the below pop-up when attempting to save, this stops by vba code from continuing to run.

[image: document classification]

I tried

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

but no luck the pop-up still appears. In addition, I tried to record a macro while selecting the classification level, but that too did not work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this is a built-in part of Excel or MS Office.  It looks like an add-on.  Try checking add-in settings, or Options under the File menu.

Comment: Thank you, TITUS was an excel add-on provoking classification. Once this was removed I was able to run no problem.